# Why is my query returning "OK" instead of rows?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    (sign(mr.p1_h2h_win_one_time - mr.p2_h2h_win_one_time)) AS h2h_win_one_time_1,
    (abs(mr.p1_h2h_win_one_time - mr.p2_h2h_win_one_time) ^ 2) AS h2h_win_one_time_2
FROM belgarath.match_result AS mr
LIMIT 10
```

Which returns:

[image]

However, when I try to multiply the two fields:

```
SELECT 
(
    sign(mr.p1_h2h_win_one_time - mr.p2_h2h_win_one_time)
) * 
(
    abs(mr.p1_h2h_win_one_time - mr.p2_h2h_win_one_time) ^ 2
) AS h2h_win_one_time_comb
FROM belgarath.match_result AS mr
LIMIT 10
```

Workbench simply returns `OK` instead of any rows.

Doing some investigation I can get the first two rows to display if I use `LIMIT 2`. Looking at the returned values above I guess there must be some issue with multiplying the minus values or zero values from rows 3-10. However, this can be done simply on a calculator so what am I missing?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Just so I'm crystal clear - I think I should have also included a `CREATE` statement so people don't have to create test data themselves? Anything else?

Comment: In addition to the points provided under the accepted answer at the linked question, please never again post a picture of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you think that the operator `^` is the power operator when in fact it is the [Bitwise XOR operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-functions.html#operator_bitwise-xor).

MySql has the function [`pow()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_pow) for your case:

```
pow(abs(mr.p1_h2h_win_one_time - mr.p2_h2h_win_one_time), 2)
```